# how to avoid indentation problem with ESlint?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, eslint

I hadn`t had this problem before I started using Vue 3 with ESlint. But now anytime I run my code I get multiple errors like:

```
C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\salam\src\views\HomeView.vue
2:1  error  Unexpected tab character  no-tabs
3:1  error  Unexpected tab character  no-tabs
4:1  error  Unexpected tab character  no-tabs
5:1  error  Unexpected tab character  no-tabs
6:1  error  Unexpected tab character  no-tabs
```

C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\salam\src\views\Login.vue
2:1   error  Unexpected tab character                            no-tabs
3:1   error  Unexpected tab character                            no-tabs
4:1   error  Unexpected tab character                            no-tabs
10:1   error  Unexpected tab character                            no-tabs
10:1   error  Expected indentation of 2 spaces but found 1 tab    indent
10:8   error  Component name "Login" should always be multi-word  vue/multi-word-component-names
11:1   error  Unexpected tab character                            no-tabs
11:1   error  Expected indentation of 2 spaces but found 1 tab    indent
12:1   error  Unexpected tab character                            no-tabs
12:1   error  Expected indentation of 4 spaces but found 2 tabs   indent
13:1   error  Unexpected tab character                            no-tabs
13:1   error  Expected indentation of 2 spaces but found 1 tab    indent
15:10  error  Newline required at end of file but not found       eol-last

✖ 18 problems (18 errors, 0 warnings)
5 errors and 0 warnings potentially fixable with the `--fix` option.

How can I disable this nasty feature of ESlint. How to make it not to pay attention to indentation or what is wrong my indentation and how can I make it correct...

Comment: Keeping code tidy is the purpose of eslint. If you don't need it, don't use it. You can learn to use a tool instead of fighting it. The editor can be configured to automatically fix lint errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to turn off tab character.You can open the **`.eslintrc.js`** file  and add a line rule.

```
rules: {
  'no-tabs': 'off'
}
```

But if you have just had enough, you can remove eslint from your project altogether.

This takes a few steps but it isn't too difficult:

- Delete `.eslintrc.js` file and `.eslintignore` file in your project
- In your package.json, find and delete any dependencies which include eslint in the name
- Remove any eslint configuration files, including any eslint configuration in package.json
- Re-run `npm install` or `yarn` to clean up your project
- Check any webpack configs for eslint loaders and references and delete those

Comment: should I serve my projec again after updating eslintrc.js ?

Comment: @user536475 `Eslint` can help you maintain code norms and prevent you from making some code mistakes. I suggest that you can turn off some rules to use it instead of completely moving it out of the project.
[Eslint Doc](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/)